# React / Firebase : Sort querySnapshot push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following:

```
const useItems = () => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const user1 = user.uid;
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("items")
        .where("User", "==", user1)
        .orderBy("Category", "asc")
        .get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              options.push({
                  value: doc.data().Name.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                  label: doc.data().Name,
                  Weight: doc.data().Weight
              });
              });
          })
  });
}
```

How can I sort the options.push by label ascending (a-z) in the querySnapshot?

Comment: Where is `options` defined?

Comment: I use options within a select ... <Select classNamePrefix="select" ref={myRef} placeholder="Select" name="Select" value={inputField.item} options={options} />

Comment: I think the question has been asked wrong?  maybe my understanding is wrong. But I think you want to sort the array options in ascending order by the label alphabetical order not so? if that is it, then sort the array in the select. e.g. ` <Select classNamePrefix="select" ref={myRef} placeholder="Select" name="Select" value={inputField.item} options={options.sort((a,b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label))} />`, All in all try a couple of things on the frontend side in that regard.